# Build several routes,taking endpoints from array on HERE maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm building web app, which should build quite big amount of routes, and show their distances. Start waypoint is constant for all routes. I try to do that like this

```js
function calculateRouteFromAtoB (platform, end) {
    var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
        routeRequestParams = {
            mode: 'fastest;truck;traffic:enabled',
            height: '7',
            weightPerAxle: '4',
            trailersCount: '1',
            routeattributes : 'sh,bb,gr',
            dirtRoad: '-3',
            tollroad:'-3',
            //tunnelCategory: 'E',
            //maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
            'waypoint0': '50.6431675,29.9479832', 
            'waypoint1': end  
        };

    router.calculateRoute(
        routeRequestParams,
        onSuccess,
        onError
    );
}

var tt;
for(tt=0;tt<array_with_endpoints.length;tt++){
    calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform,array_with_endpoints[tt]);
}
```

Function `calculateRouteFromAtoB` adds route to map and its distance to panel,but the problem is that route length on panel doesn`t match real route length. I think, that endpoints are chosen randomly. If you know, how to make this code choose endpoints by order, let me know, please.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into matrix routing?
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-matrix-of-routes.html